# How to tune Spark to avoid sort disk spill?

Tags: apache-spark

We have an algorithm that currently processes data in partition-by-partition manner `foreachPartition`. I realize this might not be the best way to process data in Spark but, in theory, we should be able to make it work.

We have an issue with Spark spilling data after `sortWithinPartitions` call with approx `45 GB` of data in partition. Our executor has `250 GB` memory defined. In theory, there is enough space to fit the data in the memory (unless Spark's overhead for sorting is huge). Yet we experience the spills. Is there a way accurately calculate how much memory per executor we'd need to make it work?

Comment: sortWithinPartitions won't do the shuffle but what are the operations that you are doing after that which is causing your data to spill..     Is there a Data skew in the dataset that you are processing?

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya technically there is a skew now but there won't be in the future (currently one partition has 16 GB, other 32 GB, the rest is less than 2 GB in size). after sort I just do foreachPartition

Comment: It hard to suggest without seeing the actual code and how it is creating stages and task in the spark UI. But if your executor is having 250 GB memory then that should not be an issue at all unless there is something odd that is happening.

Comment: Did you have a chance tuning the configuration to avoid spilling?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease a number of tasks per executor or to increase memory.

The first option is just to decrease `spark.executor.cores`

The second option obviously is to increase `spark.executor.memory`

The third option is to increase `spark.task.cpus` because number of tasks per executor are `spark.executor.cores` / `spark.task.cpus`. For example you set `spark.executor.cores=4` and `spark.task.cpus=2`. Number of tasks in that case would be 4/2=2. And if you don't set `spark.task.cpus`, by default it is 1, 4/1=4 tasks which would consume much more memory.

I prefer the third option because it keeps a balance between occupied memory and cores and allow to use more than one core per task.